# Find out from which url your API called

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm using web api.My question is:  I have to check from where call is coming in Global.asax(Application_AcquireRequestState) because I have to restrict some calls which are coming from unknown urls for the purpose of web api security.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241976/get-url-of-referer-page-in-asp-net

Comment: You shouldn't restrict (or allow) purely on IP address; instead use a scheme such as OAuth to validate **every** request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Request.UserHostAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.httprequestbase.userhostaddress%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to get the IP address from which the call is coming and  [`Request.UrlReferrer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Web.HttpRequest.UrlReferrer%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) to get the URL that linked to the current URL.

Comment: But it gives me a Null value(I tried).

Comment: I used Request.UserHostAddress(give me a IPADDRESS).Is it right approach if i used this..???:)

Comment: Yes, that should be the right one. (edited the answer)